# Jquery auto complete

Tags: jquery-ui

i want to style the autofill control scrollbar. 
max and delay properties is not working in the jquery auto fill control. 
i want to show alternate background colors in the menu item.

iam using jquery 1.4.4 and jquery-ui-1.8.7, jquery-ui-themes-1.8.7

do you have solution for this problem.

```
  $('#zipcode').autocomplete({
                    minLength: 4,
                    max: 2,
                    delay: 10,
                    source: data.d,
                    focus: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#zipcode').val(ui.item.Zip);
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#zipcode').val(ui.item.Zip);
                        $('#state').val(ui.item.Abbreviation);
                        $('#city').val(ui.item.Name);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I implemented alternate background color:

```
$('#myautocomplete').autocomplete({
    source: ...,
    ...
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $("li.ui-menu-item:odd").each(function () {
            rdaJq(this).addClass("autocomplete-item-alternate");
        });
    }
});
```

Where "autocomplete-item-alternate" is a css class I defined in a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin does not support a max option - 
[jQuery UI Autocomplete Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

Adding alternate background colors can be done by modifying the refresh method of ui.widget

```
var items = this.element.children("li:even:not(.ui-menu-item):has(a)")
        .addClass("ui-menu-item even")
        .attr("role", "menuitem");
```